# syntax error: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I'm using Python 2.7.13 in spyder.

```
def test(a,b,c='c',*args):
    for item in args:
        print item
```

This function definition is valid in Python 2.7, but as soon as I try to pass in args it gives me the *non-keyword arg after keyword arg* error:

```
test(1,2,c='c',10,11)
```

Gives this:

```
non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

But this:

```
test(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Is working.

I'm not sure what's the issue here since putting the `*args` bfore `c='c'`

```
def test(a,b,*args,c='c'):
    for item in args:
        print item
```

This gives me an error in the function definition.

The above code is just a dummy example the original code looks like the following:

```
def export_plot_as_mat(fname, undersamp, undersamp_type, n_comp, b_s, n_iter, fit_alg, transf_alg, alpha_train, alpha_test, export_info=False, *args):

    info = ('undersampling=' + str(undersamp) + ' undersampling_type=' +str(undersamp_type) + 
        ' n_comp=' + str(n_comp) + ' batch_size=' + str(b_s) + 
        ' n_iter=' + str(n_iter) + ' fit_alg=' + str(fit_alg) + 
        ' transform_alg=' + str(transf_alg) + ' alpha_train=' + 
        str(alpha_train) + ' alpha_test=' + str(alpha_test))

    d = [(str(args[i]), args[i]) for i in range(len(args))]

    if export_info:
        d.append('info',info)
    sp.io.savemat(fname + '.mat', d)
```

I want to have the option to export the parameters used to build the data I'm exporting.

Comment: Change the order: `test(1,2,10,11,c='c')`. Python will do the right thing and collect all non-keyword arguments in `*args`.

Comment: @Boldewyn this might work in python 3.x but in python 2.7 this gives me that error `test() got multiple values for keyword argument 'c'`

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig i want the args to have different sizes so that's why i just don't pass a regular parameter

Comment: The duplicate is geared more towards a Python 3 solution, whereas OP is using Python 2.7.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy since the order of definition is correct in this case it's not the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is fine, since `c` can be specified positionally. The *call* is the problem; you specified a keyword argument before another positional argument.

Python 2.x doesn't have a way to define keyword-only arguments.

Comment: as stated above, putting the *args before the keyword raises an error in the function definition

Comment: Yes, that's a second error. It doesn't change the fact that the first definition is fine.

Comment: No matter how you define `test` in Python 2.x, a call like `test(1,2,c=3,4,5)` is illegal; you cannot specify positional arguments after a keyword argument.

Comment: so a way around this would be to define the `c` in the `**kwargs` argument and call it with `kwargs[0]`, somehow i thought it might work in the manner of the question since the definition is ok.

Comment: The definition is OK because Python 2 doesn't provide a firm distinction between "optional positional argument" and "keyword argument". If you define `def test(a, b, *args, **kwargs)`, then `c` can *only* be specified as a keyword argument. (Which is subtly different from my previous claim that Python 2 doesn't have keyword-only arguments, because you aren't explicitly declare `c` in this case; you are simply claiming that `test` can take arbitrary keyword arguments, but you aren't promising that they will all be acknowledged.)

Comment: Python 3 lets you define `def test(a, *, c=5)` which is a function that accepts only 1 positional argument (binding it to `a`), and will raise an error if you specify a keyword argument other than `c`.

Comment: (And it would be `kwargs['c']`, not `kwargs[0]`.)

Comment: Thanks i think that resolved the question. I didnt understand what you meant with keyword-only in the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here.

When change the `c = 'c'` in your test() to just `'c'`

also u can put your last to arguments in a list to print them on the same line. or leave them as is to print them in separate lines.

```
def test(a,b,c='c',*args):
    for item in args:
        print item

test(1,2,'c',[10,11])
```

result:

```
[10, 11]
```

For the argument `c = 'c'` you can pass anything you want there and interact with `c`:

Take this example:

```
def test(a,b,c='c',*args):
    print c
    for item in args:
        print item


test(1,2,'g',10,11)
```

Result:

```
g
10
11
```

Comment: i want to specify the 'c' as c='c' to see to what that 'c' is assigned

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on this? what do you mean to see what the `'c'` is assigned. Maybe use an example that is not `c` on both sides of `=` so I can understand what you need.

Comment: in the updated question the argument is `export_info=False` so in the function call it is visible wheter the info should be exported too or just the parameters. just passing `True` or `False` is not readable imo

Comment: according to this [Link](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=keyword%20args#keyword-arguments) I don't think this is possible in python 2.7. I am unsure if there is a way around this for 2.7 but might be possible in python 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting side case of how Python 2.x does argument parsing. Roughly, Python has some logic for how to "match up" the arguments you pass to a function with the arguments that it is expecting, and this logic changed in Python 3.

The easiest way to get what you want is to accept `**kwargs` instead of specifying `c=0`, and do the default argument manually.

Comment: i thought of this as a solution but it is kind of ugly in the end. The defintion somehow contradicts the function call itself